# How to understand the Object.getClass() method?

Tags: java

[The Java `Object.getClass()` method javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) says:

> Returns the runtime class of this `Object`. The returned `Class` object is
>   the object that is locked by `static synchronized` methods of the
>   represented class. The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>`
>   where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which
>   `getClass` is called. For example, no cast is required in this code
>   fragment:
>
> ```
> Number n = 0; 
> Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
> ```
>
> Returns: The `Class` object that represents the runtime class of this
>   object.

What is the runtime class?

What does "returned `Class` object ... is locked by `static synchronized` methods" mean?

Comment: The class at runtime.

Comment: Why vote to close ? This is perfectly clear...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getClass` gives you the `Class` instance for the object's *actual class at runtime*, rather than the type of the reference that you have to it.

A simple example will probably clarify. Say we have a method that accepts anything that implements `List` and dumps out its class name;

```
static void foo(List l) {
    System.out.println(l.getClass().getName());
}
```

We can call it with various different types of lists:

```
foo(new LinkedList()); // Outputs "java.util.LinkedList"
foo(new ArrayList());  // Outputs "java.util.ArrayList"
```

Since `foo` can be called with any `List`, in the rare (!) situations where it's unavoidable, it can use `getClass` to figure out the actual class of the instance it's been given.

> How to understand returned Class object is locked by static synchronized methods?

`static synchronized` methods synchronize on the instance of `Class` that represents the loaded class at runtime, so that calls to such methods can't overlap. Say I have a class, `Foo`, with a static method `notThreadSafe`, and I have two threads that need to call it:

```
// On thread 1
Foo.notThreadSafe();

// On thread 2
Foo.notThreadSafe();
```

Because it's not thread safe, `notThreadSafe` would be declared `synchronized`:

```
public static synchronized void notThreadSafe() { 
    /* ... */
}
```

Which is effectively the same as

```
public static void notThreadSafe() { 
    synchronized (Foo.class) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

(`Foo.class` is the `Class` instance for the loaded `Foo` class.)

So when thread 1 enters the synchronized block, if thread 2 tries to enter that block (or anything else synchronized on `Foo.class`), it has to wait.

It doesn't have to be two calls to the same method; I could have two `static synchronized` methods (`m1` and `m2`), where thread 1 is calling `m1` and thread 2 is calling `m2`, and the call to `m2` would have to wait for the call to `m1` to complete, because they're both synchronizing on the same instance (the `Class` instance for `Foo`).

How does this relate to `getClass()`? Because that same `Class` instance is what `getClass` on `Foo` instances returns:

```
System.out.println(Foo.class == (new Foo()).getClass()); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

"Runtime class" is the Class object associated with the effective type of the object. It means if you do :

```
Object o = new String();
System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

You will get `class java.lang.String`, because the actual, runtime class of `o` is `String`. You can't predict this at compile time.

As for the "locked by synchronized static methods", it really means that, for a method declared inside class `ThisClass` :

```
public static synchronized foo() {
    ...
}
```

... is equivalent to :

```
public static foo() {
    synchronized(ThisClass.class) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That is, the Class object is used as the lock for all synchronized static methods. More on synchronized blocks and locks [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Answer (score 0):

For your second question that means that with:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
  public static synchronized void f() {}
}
...
A a = new B();
Class <? extends A> c = a.getClass();
```

a call to `f()` on `c` (only possible via reflection) will effectively use the same lock as `B.f()`. The lock will be the class object itself.